# How to show the residual sum of squares of one model is at least the residual sum of squares of another?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, regression-coefficients, linear

[image]

This question has really been bugging me and I'm failing to understand it conceptually. I don't see why it is the case and would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is important:

> all predictors in the first model are also contained [in] the second model.

So let's just assume that $X_1$ contains the first columns of $X_2$ (we can always reorder the columns of $X_2$ otherwise, this won't change anything.

Consider the solution $\gamma_1$ of the first model, which yields some $SS_{\text{Res},1}$.

If we fill $\gamma_1$ up with zeros to match the dimensionality of the second model, we get a feasible solution to the second model. Note that the $SS$ of this solution is exactly $SS_{\text{Res},1}$, since all additional predictors enter with zero coefficients.

However, we now have the freedom to change the coefficients of the second model to yield an even better fit $\beta$, i.e., one with $SS_{\text{Res},2}<SS_{\text{Res},1}$. This may or may not be possible, but we will always have at least $SS_{\text{Res},1}\geq SS_{\text{Res},2}$.

Conceptually: since the larger model encompasses the smaller one, the optimum fit for the smaller model will always be feasible for the larger one, so $SS$ will always go down (or stay constant) if we enlarge the model.